# Orientation - a trivialization over the 0-skeleton that extends over the 1-skeleton

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, vector-bundles

In learning about spin structures I was told the following: Given a manifold $X$ with a cell decomposition and a bundle $E$ over $X$, $E$ is orientable if and only if there is a trivialization of $E$ over the 0-skeleton of $X$ that extends over the 1-skeleton of $X$.  Why is this true?

Comment: Because failure to be orientable implies failure along a curve. :)

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks - sorry I am a bit slow - could you elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: If there is an orientation-reversing loop, homotop it to the 1-skeleton and you see that you cannot trivialize the bundle on the 1-skeleton. Therefore, if $E$ is trivial on the 1-skeleton, then $E$ is orientable. Conversely, a vector bundle on a circle is trivial if (and only if) it is orientable (e.g., since rank $k$-bundles on a circle are classified by $\pi_0(GL(k,\Bbb R))$).